# How can I reduce the MongoDB primary's system call(clone)?

Tags: php, mongodb, system-calls

env:

1,php 5.5

2,mongodb 2.4.6  with replSet (one primary and five secondary)

3,pecl-mongo 1.5.4

4,php database config with readPreference:

```
array(
    'database'  => 'mydatabase',
    'server'    =>  'mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017,mongo4:27017,mongo5:27017,mongo6:27017/?readPreference=secondary',
    'options'   => array('replicaSet' => 'myreplica'),
    'profiling' => FALSE,
),
```

5,mongostats:

```
mognodb primary (mongostats):   5000-20000 command      10-50 update 
mongodb secondary (mongostats): 1000-1800  command  1000-4000 query
```

I found the primary node load is high and then i found a lot of system call(clone) with strace -c -p
How can I reduce the system call(the clone)?

```
# strace -c -p 3004

% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 53.80    0.020932           6      3687           clone
 13.80    0.005368           1      7374           getsockopt
 13.15    0.005116           1      7374           setsockopt
  7.90    0.003072           1      3688           select
  6.13    0.002385           1      3687           getrlimit
  5.23    0.002033           1      3687           accept
  0.00    0.000000           0       111           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0       111           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0        14         6 futex
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.038906                 29733         6 total
```

Comment: does the php driver use connection pooling? How many connections were made, according to `mongod`?

Comment: - It looks like:
- php connection mongodb primary using short connection， 
- php connection mongodb secondary with long connection 

    `# ps aux | grep php | wc -l `
    `202`
    `# netstat -n | grep ESTABLISHED | grep 10.10.21.66:27017 | wc -l`
    `5`
    `# netstat -n | grep ESTABLISHED | grep 10.10.54.11:27017 | wc -l`
    `200`

- 10.10.21.66 is mongodb primary #10.10.54.11 is mongodb secondary

Comment: Solved! Because PHPer call MongoClient::close，it isn't proper.